# Need to grep a specific string using curl

Tags: bash, curl, awk, grep

I am trying to get language code from pages by curl

I wrote below and work...

```
curl -Ls yahoo.com | grep "lang=" | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d"\"" -f 2
```

but sometimes code is different like

```
 curl -Ls stick-it.app | grep "lang=" | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d"\"" -f 2
```

they wrote like

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="he-IL">
```

I just need to get `he-IL`

If is there any other way, I would appreciate it...

Comment: Use `curl ... | grep -oP 'lang="\K[^"]+'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ curl -Ls yahoo.com | sed -n 's/^<html.* lang="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
en-US
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `gnu-grep` then using `-P` (perl regex):

```sh
curl -Ls yahoo.com | grep -oP '\slang="\K[^"]+'

he-IL
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`'s `match` function one could try following too.

```
your_curl_command | awk '
match($0,/^<html.*lang="[^"]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*lang="/,"",val)
  print val
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
your_curl_command | awk '          ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/^<html.*lang="[^"]*/){   ##using match function to match regex starting from <html till lang=" till next 1st occurrence of "
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##Creating val which has substring of matched values.
  sub(/.*lang="/,"",val)           ##Substituting everything till lang=" with NULL in val here.
  print val                        ##printing val here.
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation using `gnu awk` and a pattern with a capture group using [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

> match(string, regexp [, array])

```
curl -Ls yahoo.com | awk 'match($0, /<html [^<>]*lang="([^"]*)"/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

Output

```
en-US
```

The pattern matches

- `<html`  Match literally
- `[^<>]*` Match 0+ any char except `<` or `>`
- `lang="` Match literally
- `([^"]*)` Capture **group 1** (denoted by `a[1]` in the example code) matching 0+ times any char except `"`
- `"` Closing double quote